# Losing hyperlinks when changing cell values

Tags: excel, vba

When I use .value= and have two columns referenced the output no longer contains a hyperlink but has the original text.

I want to be able to move the "pictures" column to my other sheet an have it retain the hyperlinks.

This is the section that handles that

```
wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO13).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI15).Value
```

Here is the entire code

```
Sub Move_to_Complete()

    'O is short for Output and refers to the Destination
    'I is short for Input and refers to the Source
    
    Dim EndRowI, EndRowO As Integer
    Dim strSearchI As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsI, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim TableI, TableO As ListObject
    Dim ColNameI1, ColNameI2, ColNameI3, ColNameI4, ColNameI5 As Variant
    Dim ColNameO1, ColNameO2, ColNameO3, ColNameO4, ColNameO5 As Variant

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Fill in the search Value
    strSearchI = "COMPLETE"

    'Set Workbook Sheets and Table Name
    Set wsI = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("JOBS LIST")
    Set wsO = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("COMPLETED JOBS")
    Set TableI = wsI.ListObjects("MAIN")
    Set TableO = wsO.ListObjects("COMPLETE")
    
    'Set Column Names
    With TableI
        ColNameI1 = .ListColumns("TOOL NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameI2 = .ListColumns("PO NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameI3 = .ListColumns("PART NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameI4 = .ListColumns("CUSTOMER").Range.Column
        ColNameI6 = .ListColumns("STATUS").Range.Column
        ColNameI7 = .ListColumns("PROGRAMMING TIME").Range.Column
        ColNameI8 = .ListColumns("RUN TIME").Range.Column
        ColNameI9 = .ListColumns("MATERIAL TYPE").Range.Column
        ColNameI10 = .ListColumns("STOCK SIZE").Range.Column
        ColNameI11 = .ListColumns("MACHINE").Range.Column
        ColNameI12 = .ListColumns("PROGRAMMER").Range.Column
        ColNameI13 = .ListColumns("NOTES").Range.Column
        ColNameI14 = .ListColumns("PICTURES").Range.Column
        ColNameI15 = .ListColumns("TAGS").Range.Column
    End With
    
    With TableO
        ColNameO1 = .ListColumns("TOOL NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameO2 = .ListColumns("PO NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameO3 = .ListColumns("PART NUMBER").Range.Column
        ColNameO4 = .ListColumns("CUSTOMER").Range.Column
        ColNameO5 = .ListColumns("PROGRAMMING TIME").Range.Column
        ColNameO6 = .ListColumns("RUN TIME").Range.Column
        ColNameO7 = .ListColumns("MATERIAL").Range.Column
        ColNameO8 = .ListColumns("STOCK SIZE").Range.Column
        ColNameO9 = .ListColumns("MACHINE").Range.Column
        ColNameO10 = .ListColumns("PROGRAMMER").Range.Column
        ColNameO11 = .ListColumns("NOTES").Range.Column
        ColNameO12 = .ListColumns("PICTURES").Range.Column
        ColNameO13 = .ListColumns("TAGS").Range.Column
        ColNameO14 = .ListColumns("DATE COMPLETED").Range.Column
    End With

    EndRowI = wsI.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = EndRowI To 3 Step -1

            Do While wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI6).Value = strSearchI

                EndRowO = wsO.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO1).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI1).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO2).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI2).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO3).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI3).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO4).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI4).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO5).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI7).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO6).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI8).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO7).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI9).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO8).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI10).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO9).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI11).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO10).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI12).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO11).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI13).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO12).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI14).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO13).Value = wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI15).Value
                wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO14).Value = Date
                wsI.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Delete
                wsO.Range("A1:N" & EndRowO).sort key1:=wsO.Range("N1:N" & EndRowO), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes


            Loop

    Next i

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
        
End Sub
```

Comment: Copy/Paste: `wsI.Cells(i, ColNameI15).Copy wsO.Cells(EndRowO, ColNameO13)`

Comment: The hyperlink to a dropbox image is still not there with the pasted cell. Just the text from the copied cell.